# Troubles while importing paint weights in Maya

Tags: python, maya

The code is working half of the times.
I do not understand, why it stops and starts behave as expected.

It imports paint map on the deformer, for example, blendshape or deltaMush.
Using Maya 2019.

```
def import_paint_weights(node, painted):
    default_ctx = cmds.currentCtx()
    node_type = cmds.objectType(node)
    art_attr = cmds.artAttrCtx(oaa="%s.%s.weights" % (node_type, node))
    cmds.setToolTo(art_attr)
    cmds.artAttrCtx(art_attr, importfileload=painted,
                    ifm='luminance', edit=True)
    cmds.dgeval(node)
    cmds.setToolTo(default_ctx)

neutral = 'head_neutral'
painted = 'c:/scans/bls_painted/delta_mush_inner_mouth_zone.iff'
emotion = cmds.ls(sl=True, fl=True)
bl = cmds.blendShape(neutral, emotion)[0]
cmds.select(emotion)
import_paint_weights(bl, painted)
```

This code worked, but the problem not solved.

```
def import_paint_weights(node, painted):
    data_attr_map = {'blendShape':'baseWeights', 'deltaMush':'weights'}
    default_ctx = cmds.currentCtx()
    node_type = cmds.objectType(node)
    node_attr = data_attr_map.get(node_type, None)
    if not node_attr:
        print 'Not recognized node. Use blendshape and deltamush only now'
        return
    mel.eval('artSetToolAndSelectAttr("artAttrCtx", "%s.%s.%s")' % (node_type, node, node_attr))
    curr_ctx = cmds.currentCtx()
    cmds.artAttrCtx(curr_ctx, selectedattroper='absolute', edit=True)
    cmds.artAttrCtx(curr_ctx, edit=True, value=0)
    cmds.artAttrCtx(curr_ctx, edit=True, clear=True)
    cmds.artAttrCtx(curr_ctx, importfileload=painted,
                    ifm='luminance', edit=True)
    cmds.setToolTo(default_ctx)
```

Code that worked for 2019, is broken for 2020.
Here is the one.

```
def import_paint_weights(node, painted):
    # Select object with node before executing the function
    data_attr_map = {'blendShape':'baseWeights', 'deltaMush':'weights', 'shrinkWrap':'weights'}
    default_ctx = cmds.currentCtx()
    node_type = cmds.objectType(node)
    node_attr = data_attr_map.get(node_type, None)
    if not node_attr:
        print 'Not recognized node. Supported nodes are:'
        print data_attr_map.keys()
        return
    art_attr = cmds.artAttrCtx(oaa="%s.%s.%s" % (node_type, node, node_attr))
    cmds.setToolTo(art_attr)
    # Resets painted values to Zeroes
    # Sets paint mode to 'replace'
    cmds.artAttrCtx(art_attr, selectedattroper='absolute', edit=True)
    cmds.artAttrCtx(art_attr, edit=True, value=0)
    cmds.artAttrCtx(art_attr, edit=True, clear=True)
    cmds.artAttrCtx(art_attr, importfileload=painted,
                    ifm='luminance', edit=True)
    # cmds.dgeval(node)
    cmds.setToolTo(default_ctx)
```

Comment: have you tried to evalDeferred the import of the map ? scripts that are using ui loading are sometimes unstable

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Looked for this function and haven't found a place to insert it. 
The code above are not dealing with uis.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if it will fix your problem but i see in my scripts that im doing this when playing with the ctx menu :

```
cmds.artAttrCtx('artAttrNClothContext', edit=1, selectedattroper="smooth")
cmds.refresh()
cmds.artAttrCtx('artAttrNClothContext', edit=1, clear=1)
```

so maybe you just need to usse a refresh after modifying the ui